# In how many ways we can seat n married couples in a circle?

Tags: combinatorics

We seat n marriages at the round table,
alternately female and male. What is the probability that there won't be any marriage sitting next to each other?

In the textbook I found the answer to this and it mostly coincides with my idea, but I don't understand how to find this binomial coefficient.
Answear: $ n!n! - 2n \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}\binom{2n-k-1}{k-1}(k-1)!(n-k)!(n-k)!$

I undestand it in that way. The women can sit in odd places only so we choose one woman's chair (n ways), then her husband can be on her left or right (2 ways). Now that coefficient - we pick pairs from ramaining chairs (for the rest of marriages). And now there are $(k-1)!$ how we can assign marriages to chairs. At the end we put the rest of n-k men and n-k.

Forgive me for my English.

Comment: Your book is using inclusion-exclusion to solve the problem

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I still don't undestand where that coefficient came from

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a factor of ${n \choose k}$ in the sum, so you should have that the number of seating arrangements with no couples sitting next to each other is:

$ n!n! - 2n \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}{n \choose k}\binom{2n-k-1}{k-1}(k-1)!(n-k)!(n-k)!$

As discussed in comments, we are using the inclusion-exclusion principle to start with all seating arrangements, and then add or subtract the seating arrangements where a specific set of couples sit next to each other.  That is we add if the set has size $k$ even, and subtract if $k$ is odd.

In particular, the number of seating arrangements where $k$ specific couples sit next to each other depends only on $k$, so the contribution from sets of $k$ couples will be $(-1)^{k-1}{n\choose k}$ times the number of seating arrangements where $k$ specific couples sit next to each other.

As you pointed out, once we have seated the $k$ couples, there are $(n-k)!(n-k)!$ ways to arrange the rest.

Also, as you pointed out, there $2n$ ways to place our first couple, and once we have picked out $k-1$ disjoint pairs of adjacent seats from the remaining $n-2$ seats, there will be $(k-1)!$ ways to put the remaining $k-1$ couples in them.

Thus the final factor which we need to compute is the number of ways of picking $k-1$ disjoint pairs of adjacent seats from the $n-2$ seats in a row.  The trick here is to:

1. Remove $k-1$ seats from the $n-2$ seats,
2. Pick any $k-1$ seats from the remaining $2n-k-1$ seats in any of the $\binom{2n-k-1}{k-1}$ ways,
3. Replace the seats you removed to the right of the ones you picked, to complete your adjacent pairs.

This method will produce each combination of $k-1$ disjoint adjacent pairs exactly once, so we obtain the final required factor of $\binom{2n-k-1}{k-1}$.